# renaming excel worksheets using vba

Tags: vba

Am trying to copy a cell value and rename that worksheet as per the cell value. The cell would contain stings/integers
the following code pops an error while renaming the sheet

```
Sub Button1_Click()

'Set datasheet = Application.ActiveSheet
Dim row  As Integer
Dim col As Integer

row = 3
Column = 12
Do Until Sheets("BOM").Cells(row, Column) = ""
Sheets("Blank").Select
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("Blank").Copy After:=Sheets(1)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("BOM").Select
Sheets("Blank (2)").Select

Sheets("Blank (2)").name = Cells(row, Column).Value  ==> Code breaks here 
row = row + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: And what is the error? And which line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are getting the error due to following

You new sheet name is blank. 
 Your new sheet name is > 31 chars.
 It contains any of the following characters  `:  \  /  ?  *  [  or  ]`

There are no work-arounds for any of these. Just make sure your new name is a valid string.

Comment: it is a valid string

Comment: The sheet name before rename is Blank (2). Am trying to copy a cell content and rename this sheet with that cell content. Cell content is aRS2534

Comment: It works. You are right. The right sheet was not selected Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Dinesh,
The reason that you're getting that error is because you're trying to give the sheet an empty name (Cells(3, 12) of the newly created sheet, which, of course, will always be empty). To solve the problem you can do one of two things: either pull the name from a cell containing a value in another sheet, or put a value in Sheets("Blank (2)").Cells(row, Column) prior to setting the name. Both options are presented below:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    'Set datasheet = Application.ActiveSheet
    Dim row  As Integer
    Dim col As Integer

    row = 3
    Column = 12
    Do Until Sheets("BOM").Cells(row, Column) = ""
        Sheets("Blank").Select
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Sheets("Blank").Copy After:=Sheets(1)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Sheets("BOM").Select
        Sheets("Blank (2)").Select

        Sheets("Blank (2)").Cells(row, Column).Value = "Some_Sheet_Name"  ' <--Option #2
        Sheets("Blank (2)").Name = Cells(row, Column).Value               ' <--Option #2

       ' Sheets("Blank (2)").Name = Sheets("BOM").Cells(row, Column).Value ' <--Option #1

        row = row + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Should you have any other questions, please don't hesitate to ask.